# Cast sqlite prepare to a custom model

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I want to cast result into a ModelA array but did not figure out a way.

```
let query = "SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 ..."
let results = try! db.prepare(query) as Array<ModelA>() // I do not know how to cast
```

ModelA:

```
Struct ModelA: Codable{
let columnA: String
let columnB: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast directly, try using `map` on the result

```
let models = results.map { ModelA(columnA: $0[0], columnB: $0[1] }
```